# How do I add a <select> input to the product variantForm in Reaction Commerce?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

How do I get a `<select>` drop-down menu in the product `varientForm`?

Something like what we see here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish adding a `<select>` to variantForm as seen above we need to edit or extend three files, `variantForm.html`, `variantForm.js` and the `products.js` schema:

- [reaction/imports/plugins/included/product-variant/client/templates/products/productDetail/variants/variantForm/variantForm.html](https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction/blob/master/imports/plugins/included/product-variant/client/templates/products/productDetail/variants/variantForm/variantForm.html)
- [reaction/imports/plugins/included/product-variant/client/templates/products/productDetail/variants/variantForm/variantForm.js](https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction/blob/master/imports/plugins/included/product-variant/client/templates/products/productDetail/variants/variantForm/variantForm.js)
- [reaction/lib/collections/schemas/products.js](https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction/blob/master/lib/collections/schemas/products.js)

In the [AutoForm live example](http://autoform.meteorapp.com/types) of `<select>` we see a schema that looks like this:

```
{
  typeTest: {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
      type: "select",
      options: function () {
        return [
          {label: "2013", value: 2013},
          {label: "2014", value: 2014},
          {label: "2015", value: 2015}
        ];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and a [Blaze](http://blazejs.org/guide/introduction.html) template HTML that looks like this:

```
{{#autoForm id="types2" schema=typesSchema2}}
  {{> afFormGroup name="typeTest" type="select" options=optionsHelper}}
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
{{/autoForm}}
```

---

#### Step 1

Edit/extend `products.js` schema file adding your select except we only need to add these parts:

```
typeTest: {
  type: String,
  optional: true,
  autoform: {
    type: "select"
  }
},
```

Reaction Commerce ignores the `optionHelper` function from AutoForm as we see in the above example. I keep the `autoform: { type: "select" }` just to express intension. For a real-world example of a `product.js` schema modified this way see [here](https://github.com/MassDistributionMedia/rc-ca-blinds/blob/master/lib/collections/schemas/products.js#L245).

---

#### Step 2

Add your helper function to `variantForm.js` that returns your selection's options object. Inside `Template.variantForm.helpers({})` add:

```
variantTypeOptions: function (){
  return [
    {label: "Default", value: 2013},
    {label: "Height & Weight", value: "Height & Weight"}
  ];
},
```

Nice and simple (and similar to the AutoForm example), these become the selection options we see in the screenshot above. Real-world example [here](https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction/blob/master/imports/plugins/included/product-variant/client/templates/products/productDetail/variants/variantForm/variantForm.js#L22).

---

#### Step 3

Final step. Let's lastly add the Blaze template HTML to `variantForm.html`:

```
<div class="form-group{{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='variantType'}} has-error{{/if}}">
  <label class="control-label">{{afFieldLabelText name='variantType'}}</label>
  {{>afFieldInput name='variantType' type="select" options=variantTypeOptions}}
  {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='variantType'}}
    <span class="help-block">{{afFieldMessage name='variantType'}}</span>
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

With our focus on:

`{{>afFieldInput name='variantType' type="select" options=variantTypeOptions}}`

Real-world example [here](https://github.com/MassDistributionMedia/rc-ca-blinds/blob/master/imports/plugins/included/product-variant/client/templates/products/productDetail/variants/variantForm/variantForm.html#L58).

---

Closing Remarks

You may need to do a [`rc reset`](https://docs.reactioncommerce.com/reaction-docs/master/creating-a-plugin) for the changes to the schema to take effect, but **WARNING**, this will wipe your local development database. See the note in the RC Docs about having to do frequent resets in the "[Creating a Plugin](https://docs.reactioncommerce.com/reaction-docs/master/creating-a-plugin)" article.